# Convert a string to array of number and alphabets

Tags: javascript

```
var string;
var splitstring = string.split("????");
```

my string is 12BLG123
i need the array splitstring to have elements 12,BLG,123
(The alphabets and numbers randomly vary)

Comment: Do  you want to seperate alphabet and number ?

Comment: split won't do, use regex

Comment: i want an array split into elements as given above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
const string = `12BLG123`
const splitString = string.split(/(\d+)/).filter(i => i)

console.log(splitString)
```

The regex splits the string by numeric strings. Since split doesn't include the value that it is being split by, we use the capturing syntax to include the numeric strings. Empty strings are introduced if the string starts or ends with numeric strings so we use `filter(i => i)` to remove the empty strings (it works because empty strings are falsey values in javascript).

Answer (score 2):

Though not regex or split, but you can do something like this,

```js
var str = "12BLG123";

var result = [].reduce.call(str, (acc, a) => {
    if (!acc.length) return [a];    // initial case
    let last = acc[acc.length - 1];
    // same type (digit or char)
    if (isNaN(parseInt(a, 10)) == isNaN(parseInt(last.charAt(0), 10))) 
        acc[acc.length - 1] = last + a;
    // different type
    else acc.push(a);
    // return the accumulative
    return acc;
}, [] /* the seed */);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex will probably work.

`var splitString = string.split("[^A-Z0-9]+|(?<=[A-Z])(?=[0-9])|(?<=[0-9])(?=[A-Z])");`